# PHP - Replacing characters with stars, except when there is a minus

Tags: php

How can I replace a string with stars except the first and the last letter **but not** a minus **in case there is one**. 
Here for better illustration what I try to get:
**From**:
url-name
**To**
u**-***e

This is what I have so far:

```
function get_starred($str) {
        $len = strlen($str);
return substr($str, 0, 1).str_repeat('_', $len - 2).substr($str, $len - 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: So you want to replace all letters, except the first and last, and dashes?

Comment: correct thats what I'm trying :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey try implmenting the following:

```
function get_starred($str) {
  $str_array =str_split($str);
 foreach($str_array as $key => $char) {
  if($key == 0 || $key == count($str_array)-1) continue;
  if($char != '-') $str[$key] = '*';
 }
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: beat me too it.  However, this only works for single words (no spaces)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [PCRE verbs](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) to skip the first character of a string, last character of a string, and any `-`s. Like this:

```
(^.|-|.$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.
```

https://regex101.com/r/YfrZ8r/1/

PHP example using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace('/(^.|-|.$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|./', '*', 'url-name');
```

https://3v4l.org/0dSPQ

Answer (score 2):

[user3783242 has a great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52768211/5827005) - However, if you for some reason do not want to use `preg_replace()`, you could do the following:

```
function get_starred($str) {

    //make the string an array of letters
    $str = str_split($str);

    //grab the first letter (This also removes the first letter from the array)
    $first = array_shift($str);

    //grab the last letter (This also removes the last letter from the array)
    $last = array_pop($str);

    //loop through leftover letters, replace anything not a dash
    //note the `&` sign, this is called a Reference, it means that if the variable is changed in the loop, it will be changed in the original array as well.
    foreach($str as &$letter) {

        //if letter is not a dash, set it to an astrisk.
        if($letter != "-") $letter = "*";
    }

    //return first letter, followed by an implode of characters, followed by the last letter.
    return $first . implode('', $str) . $last;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine:

```
$string = 'url-name foobar';

function star_replace($string){
    return preg_replace_callback('/[-\w]+/i', function($match){
       $arr = str_split($match[0]);
       $len = count($arr)-1;
       for($i=1;$i<$len;$i++) $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] == '-' ? '-' : '*';
       return implode($arr);
    }, $string);

}

echo star_replace($string);
```

This works on multiple words.

Output

```
u**-***e f****r
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e55e73eec1f61f95bfaad2a958bb94429f98582)

And it also takes into account puctuation

```
$string = 'url-name foobar.';
```

Output

```
u**-***e f****r.
```